# can't install Zend optimizer

Tags: php, apache, zend-optimizer

I downloaded template which requires Zend optimizer installed.

1) I installed WAMP 
2) copied template content in to /localhost directory
3) Installed Zend Optimizer (in installation process setter path to apache, php.ini)
4) Started WAMP

And got message

> CMS Server Tester
>   Your server was tested to meet all CMS requirements. Following errors were encountered an need to be fixed to run the software:

```
PHP extension "curl" is not loaded.
Please verify your server configuration. Make sure that extension "curl" is enabled.
PHP extension "Zend Optimizer|Zend Guard Loader" is not loaded.
Please verify your server configuration. Make sure that extension "Zend Optimizer|Zend Guard Loader" is enabled.
```

What is the problem? I made anything according to instructions

Answer (score 0):

the error is suggesting that you need to enable "php_curl" under the php extensions in WAMP.  Do that then restart WAMP and see what happens